# Creating a list with editable items to get information from user

Tags: android, listview

Suppose we have a bunch of files. I want to show them in a list that each item has some editable fields, user fills them and at the end, clicks on save button to make changes to items.

I tried a `ListView` with custom adapter having some `EditText`s on it. but when I try to save, I don't know how to retrieve edited fields for each item and save changes to them. I think `ListView` is not for that purpose. It is just for representing items for user. What should I do?

Comment: use Recyclerview instead of listview.http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/169/recyclerview#t=201609120900539732104

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: @shalini Thank you shalini, `RecyclerView` Helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. Create arraylist of models which will hold all values inserted into editable and this arraylist will be in the activity class where listview is implemented. Then in list adapter handle click for editable based on position and whatever value is there in editable store it instantly in arraylist. That's it !

Comment: `RecyclerView` is an advanced `ListView` that implements all you said. btw thanks.